# Ajax request getting wrong url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have had a search for this but normally this is due to people not respecting paths. This is not my issue!

code:

```
function getpass(){
var passwd = document.getElementById('box').value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.response);
        document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = this.response;
    }
};
var redurl = "./required/crypt.php?a=gp&pass="+encodeURI(passwd);
console.log(redurl);
xhttp.open("GET",redurl,true);
xhttp.send();
```

}

The error is on xhttp.send();. The console logs (with ref lines in brackets):

```
/required/crypt.php?a=gp&pass=tset (console.log(redurl);)
login.php:71 GET http://localhost/required/login.php 404 (Not Found)
    getpass @   login.php:71 (xhttp.send();)
    onclick @   login.php:46 (<button onclick="getpass()">genPasswd</button>)
```

login.php is the at the document root (localhost/login.php), crypt.php is in the required folder (localhost/required/crypt.php)

Why is it trying to redirect to "localhost/required/login.php"? You can see from the logs that 'redurl' is working as expected but ajax is deciding to ignore the url but not the folder? This is a function to generate a password for testing purposes, i have 20 - 30 functions pretty much the same as this one all working correctly, its just this single function that is failing.

Comment: Sounds like your backend is saying that the user is not logged in and is trying to redirect it to the log in page. And the redirect logic is not using the correct path.

Comment: Yeah, seems like your crypt.php must be doing something like:
On error -> header("Location: ./login.php"); that will throw a 404 error because your login.php is not inside required folder.

Comment: spent an hour trying to figure that one out. you were right my crypto.php included a file for session management that was incorrectly redirecting to login.php, thought i had already disabled that in the crypt.php file but was also in the session.php file as well.